# iOS Safari text selection really difficult

Tags: ios, safari

I'm frequently having huge issues selecting text in iOS Safari (and other apps using WebKit). See this video for an example, where I'm visiting Ars Technica and try to select the name of a commenter (mr/ms "Twilight Sparkle"):

Video (24 MB, 1 minute): 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dw81yibdn56j60s/iOS-9-select-text.mov

I used a full minute to select the name, and even then, the text selection guides indicate that something is SNAFU.

This frequently occurs on sites where OS X Safari allows flawless text selection, so to me this looks like a bug, or at least a very poorly implemented feature.

Non ideal solutions:

- Select too much text, paste it into **Notes** and then select a subset of the text.
- **Zooming** – doesn't solve the issue consistently
- **Reader** mode – isn't always available
- **Jailbreaking** – feels like overreacting

Other tips for how to improve this situation?

Comment: And this only happens in Safari, on certain sites?

Comment: @Daniel, apart from [Opera](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/opera-mini-web-browser/id363729560) in Mini mode, [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) is the only layout engine that's allowed on non jailbroken iOS devices. I have tested Chrome and Firefox for iOS, and they have the same symptoms. And yes, this is dependent on site, but there is a large percentage of sites that have the problem.

Comment: Does this ever happen in Mail, Notes, or Calendar?

Comment: If so it may be your fingers...